# how to locate cursors randomly in map

Tags: css, testing, xpath, selenium, selenium-ide

a lot of cursors in the map
every time you refresh the map you  will get another different cursors with different IDs
so i can't use the IDs to test random cursors

i want to click at any cursor, tooltip should appear when i click any of them
i tried lots of things but i can't do it :(
please help

all cursor details

```
map id="gmimap208" name="gmimap208">
<area log="miw" coords="11,0,12,1,13,2,14,3,14,4,14,5,14,6,14,7,14,8,14,9,14,10,13,11,12,12,12,13,11,14,10,15,10,16,9,17,9,18,8,19,7,20,7,20,7,19,6,18,6,17,5,16,4,15,4,14,3,13,2,12,2,11,1,10,1,9,0,8,0,7,0,6,0,5,1,4,1,3,2,2,2,1,4,0,11,0" shape="poly" title="" style="cursor: pointer;">
</map>



<div class="gmnoprint" style="width: 15px; height: 21px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; opacity: 0.01; left: 373px; top: 370px; z-index: 2000;">
<img style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 15px; height: 21px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" src="/img/property_icons/free/normal.png" draggable="false" usemap="#gmimap226">
<map id="gmimap226" name="gmimap226">
```

Xpaths
for cursor 1

```
/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[50]/map/area
```

for cursor 2

```
/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[25]/map/area
```

for cursor 3

```
/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[9]/map/area
```

css

```
html.win body.rtl div.content-for-layout div#page-container table tbody tr td div#Map div div div div div div.gmnoprint map#gmimap83 area
```

html

```
<area log="miw" coords="11,0,12,1,13,2,14,3,14,4,14,5,14,6,14,7,14,8,14,9,14,10,13,11,12,12,12,13,11,14,10,15,10,16,9,17,9,18,8,19,7,20,7,20,7,19,6,18,6,17,5,16,4,15,4,14,3,13,2,12,2,11,1,10,1,9,0,8,0,7,0,6,0,5,1,4,1,3,2,2,2,1,4,0,11,0" shape="poly" title="" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

Comment: If this is Google maps, I'd totally avoid this at all costs. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am now working on automated test the whole site,  so i want to make sure that map page works well,  and when the user click on any cursor the tooltip will appear

thanks for your comment but why you advises me to avoid it ?
help me more please

Comment: Rather than doing it randomly you could put all elements into an ArrayList then iterate through each one and click on each and verify the tooltip. Alternatively, you could still put them into an ArrayList, generate a random number between 0 - ArrayList.size() and click on that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you everyone for trying help me :)
i finally did it

just

```
|click | //map/area | |
```

this command clicks at the first ID cursor in map page
:)

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure as to what you're trying to test?

However, if the xpath for each cursor is determined by the final div[x] could you not parameterise that value (x)?

Comment: i want to click at any cursor, tooltip should appear when i click any of them
i tried you solution but it didn't work :(  thank you for help